# How to find the size of an array inside of an object in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in jquery tied to a button that, when clicked, will put all of the checkboxes that have been checked on my page into an array. The function contains this code:

```
var selectedinterests = {'interests[]' : []};
$("input[name='interests[]']:checked").each(function () {
  selectedinterests['interests[]'].push($(this).val());
});
```

After this has been executed how do I find the count of how many items are in interests[]? I have been trying lots of different methods I've found on google but nothing seems to work. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `selectedinterests['interests[]'].length`

Comment: @Pointy Thank you very much!